# Debugging in Intelij works through the test spec but not directly through the main code

Tags: micronaut

In an existing micronaut service profile application I added the picocli dependencies, and created a command and a command test spec. When I debug the command through Intellij, the annotated variables do not get injected. Specifically the ingestClient is null. When I debug the spock spec, injection does occur. Is there something I am  missing?

This is the command:

```
package abbvie.esp.ingest.attache

import abbvie.esp.ingest.attache.model.LoadResult
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import io.micronaut.configuration.picocli.PicocliRunner
import io.reactivex.Flowable
import picocli.CommandLine.Command
import picocli.CommandLine.Option

import javax.inject.Inject

@CompileStatic
@Command(name = 'ingest', description = 'Command line tool to control ingestion of Attache Pro content into the search index.',
        mixinStandardHelpOptions = true)
class IngestCommand implements Runnable {

    @Inject
    IngestClient ingestClient

    @Option(names = ['-v', '--verbose'], description = '...')
    boolean verbose

    static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PicocliRunner.run(IngestCommand, args)
    }

    void run() {
        Flowable<LoadResult> results = ingestClient.ingestCabinets()
        for (LoadResult result : results.blockingIterable()) {
            println result.id
        }
    }
}
```

This is the spec:

```
package abbvie.esp.ingest.attache

import io.micronaut.configuration.picocli.PicocliRunner
import io.micronaut.context.ApplicationContext
import io.micronaut.context.env.Environment
import spock.lang.AutoCleanup
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification

class IngestCommandSpec extends Specification {

    @Shared
    @AutoCleanup
    ApplicationContext ctx = ApplicationContext.run(Environment.CLI, Environment.TEST)

    void "test with command line option"() {
        given:

        String[] args = ['-v'] as String[]
        PicocliRunner.run(IngestCommand, ctx, args)

        expect:
        args.length > 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A common problem is that annotation processing has not been enabled yet in IntelliJ.

You can enable annotation processing under the "Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Annotation Processors" by ticking the "Enable annotation processing" checkbox.

See also:
https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#ideSetup

PS. I hope you like [picocli](https://github.com/remkop/picocli). Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I actually did enable it because it was mentioned in the documentation. However no luck, and also side note, both the Spec test and the command are running from the IDE, so I am unsure of the difference in behavior.
I am looking forward to picocli. I was using airlift in the past.

Comment: Cool. Feel free to raise issues or feature requests on the picocli GitHub issue tracker or the picocli Google group.